# Trying to create a Kubernetes deployment but it shows 0 pods available

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm new to k8s, so some of my terminology might be off. But basically, I'm trying to deploy a simple web api: one load balancer in front of n pods (where right now, n=1).

However, when I try to visit the load balancer's IP address it doesn't show my web application. When I run kubectl get deployments, I get this:

```
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
tl-api    1         1         1            0           4m
```

Here's my YAML file. Let me know if anything looks off--I'm very new to this!

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tl-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tl-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tl-api
        image: tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-auth
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tl-api
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: tl-api
```

Edit 2: When I try using ACS (which supports Windows), I get this:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                From                   Message
  ----     ------                 ----               ----                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled              11m                default-scheduler      Successfully assigned tl-api-3466491809-vd5kg to dc9ebacs9000
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  11m                kubelet, dc9ebacs9000  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-v3wz9"
  Normal   Pulling                4m (x6 over 10m)   kubelet, dc9ebacs9000  pulling image "tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi:v1"
  Warning  FailedSync             1s (x50 over 10m)  kubelet, dc9ebacs9000  Error syncing pod
  Normal   BackOff                1s (x44 over 10m)  kubelet, dc9ebacs9000  Back-off pulling image "tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi:v1"
```

I then try examining the failed pod:

```
PS C:\users\<me>\source\repos\DeviceCloud\DeviceCloud\1- Presentation\DeviceCloud.Web.API> kubectl logs tl-api-3466491809-vd5kg
Error from server (BadRequest): container "tl-api" in pod "tl-api-3466491809-vd5kg" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

When I run `docker images` I see the following:

```
REPOSITORY                                   TAG                            IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
devicecloudwebapi                            latest                         ee3d9c3e231d        24 hours ago        7.85GB
tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi           v1                             ee3d9c3e231d        24 hours ago        7.85GB
devicecloudwebapi                            dev                            bb33ab221910        25 hours ago        7.76GB
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that the container image `tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi:v1` is in a private container registry. See the events at the bottom of the following command:

```
$ kubectl describe po -l=app=tl-api
```

The official Kubernetes docs describe how to resolve this issue, see [Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/), essentially:

- Create a secret `kubectl create secret docker-registry`
- Use it in your deployment, under the `spec.imagePullSecrets` key

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting: "Failed to pull image "tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi:v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unknown blob." Does it not recognize my image name? I'm pretty sure it's right.

Comment: Got it. Since I can't reproduce that, I can only guess: if you're using ACS, maybe you're hitting the same issue as described in here: https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2017/06/21/issue-failed-to-pull-image-rpc-error-code-2-desc-unknown-blob/?

Comment: Ah, my Google fu failed me. Thanks for the find. It looks like I can't run Windows containers currently on AKS! Thanks for your help. (For the curious, it says: "To run Windows Server containers, you need to run Windows Server-based nodes. Windows Server-based nodes are not available in AKS at this time. If you need to run Windows Server containers on Kubernetes in Azure, please see the documentation for acs-engine.")

Comment: Can I bug you again? I tried deploying with ACS now (which DOES support Windows nodes) and now I'm getting error syncing pod. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Maybe best in a separate question, to keep it clean?